# Angular 4 - Edit data from database

Tags: angular

how can I update data from database using http service.

**php mysql**

```
function updateEmployees() {
    global $con, $employeesTable;
    return $updateEmployees = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE $employeesTable SET first_name='test', last_name ='".$request->last_name."' WHERE emp_id = '".$request->user_id."' ");
}
```

**FORM**

```
<p><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first_name"></p>
<p><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="last_name"></p>
<p><input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="user_id"></p>
<button (click)="editForm()">Edit</button>
```

**service**

```
  updateEmployees(data) {
   console.log(data);
   let headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' }),
     options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   this.http.post('http://localhost/employees/?p=updateEmployees', data, options)
  .subscribe(data => data);
}
```

**component**

ON PAGE LOAD, THE FIRSTNAME AND LASTNAME I FETCHED FROM DATABASE WILL PASS THE DATA TO INPUT FORM.

```
  ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((queryParams: Params) => {
    let userId = queryParams['id'];
    this.employeesServices.getEmployeesById(userId)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.first_name = data.first_name,
        this.last_name = data.last_name,
        this.user_id = userId
      });
  });
}
```

THEN ON FORM SUBMIT, IT WILL POST THE UPDATED DATA TO DATABASE.
BUT I CANT GET IT RIGHT.

```
editForm() {
  this.myForm = new FormGroup( {
    'first_name': new FormControl(this.first_name),
    'last_name': new FormControl(this.last_name)
  } )
  this.employeesServices.updateEmployees(this.myForm.value);
}
```

the logs shows me {first_name: "input1", last_name : "input2"} but not updating to database

Comment: how to detect you need to update which employee? means you need to pass user_id when you call update

Comment: I updated my post, I add my html form. basically, on my component when page loads I have a code in php that will fetch user id using queryParams, I can get the user data of that ID I fetched and pass it to my form input  as its value. when click the button it should update and pass it to php

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="update(userform)" #userform="ngForm">
<p><input name="first_name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="first_name"></p>
<p><input name="last_name" type="text" [(ngModel)]="last_name"></p>
<p><input name="user_id" type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="user_id"></p>
<button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

**Component**

```
 update(form: NgForm) {
     console.log(form.value); // confirm value on console
     this.employeesServices.updateEmployees(form.value);
    }
```

your service should be like

```
updateEmployees(data) : Observable<any>{
   let headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json' }),
     options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
   const url = 'http://localhost/employees/?p=updateEmployees';
   return this.http.put(url, data, options).map(
            (res: Response) => {
                return res.json();
            }).catch(
            (error: Response) => {
                return Observable.throw(error.json() as JsonResponse);
            });
}
```

Comment: i used this const url = 'http://localhost/employees/?p=updateEmployees';
    return this.http.put(url, data, options).map(
      (res) => {
          return res.json();
      }); but still no luck

Comment: dont worry about the url, I just created my API in native PHP code, I created a function then when I enter the ?p=updateEmploees, my updateEmployee() function will trigger